# Photos.app library erased- recovery?

Tags: photos, hard-drive-recovery, libraries

I accidentally erased my only copy of the Photos library, which resided on an external USB drive. I have tried a service (no go- runaround on what was "recovered" from Geek Tech Support- a scam!), and then used Data Rescue from ProSoft- it found many GB's of images, but no library file that I can recognize. I am loading everything found onto another drive, so the question is; Is there any way I can reliably recover the library, or do I have to reconstruct it one folder of images at a time?

Comment: Can we assume this is Windows and you're referring to the Windows library function?  What Windows version?  What was the folder structure?  What does the recovered content look like?

Comment: No, this is the Mac OS X Photos library, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The OS X Photos Library, apart from its appearance in Finder, which shows it as a 'file' is actually a package; view it from anything other than a Mac & it looks just like a folder.

Its default name is actually Photos Library.photoslibrary
When the Finder sees that extension it automatically wraps it to look like a package.

Trouble is - the hierarchy is vast & complex & I would hold *no chance at all* of rebuilding it manually.
Grab what photos you can & start over by dragging them to a new Library in Photos.

Picture below is just a tiny hint as to what is in there - & note we don't yet see a single photo...

[image]

Comment: Hello - your response is very helpful, but I have also heard that the migrated iPhoto library also holds photos (maybe none since migration, but maybe more than I have recovered thru Data Rescue?), and somehow an Apple Genius could help me re-migrate that file into Photos. A possibility??

Comment: Forget the Library itself, that is not recoverable. Individual photos now depend on what the USB drive is & what exactly happened to it. If it's a spinning HD & you just put the Lib in Trash & emptied it - *then did nothing else* - then chances of getting the individual files back are high. If you continued to work on the drive, adding & removing files, your chances get lower. If the drive is not a spinning HD, your chances drop away to very, very low. Data Rescue is as good as any at file fragment recovery, so let it do the best it can & consider that a plus.